# Google App Engine Flexible get access to a folder dynamically created by a package?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, profiling

I am doing `Profiling` on my `NodeJs` app, I am using `Google App Engine Flexible` and for it, I am using [npm 0x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/0x), but the thing is as this package is making the `flamegraph` inside my NodeJs root directory folder, now how can I `retrieve this folder`(I mean `get access` to this folder). I have `SSH` to my App Engine Flexible instance but there were two folders `vm-runtime-app`, `vmagent` but there my NodeJs  Source code root directory is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the GAE instance launch the app into a [Docker container](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance). After you SSH to your instance, you need to spawn a shell into the container that runs your app

Here are the steps *after* you SSH to your instance:

```
sudo docker ps
docker exec -it [CONTAINER-NAME] /bin/bash
```

The first command will list running Docker containers and among them, your node runtime container (likely named `gaeapp`); the second command will spawn a bash shell within the container where you can `ls` and `cd` and `pwd` around

Once you know which directory or file you want to download, you can exit the container shell and copy your file(s) from the container to the GAE instance:

```
exit
docker cp [CONTAINER-NAME]:/app/package.json ./
```

From there you can use gcloud shell to download this file locally. You could also simply copy it within Node to an exposed http endpoint in your api (i.e. `/debug/flamegraph.svg`) after it is generated in node, just sayin'